# Export access query to same sheet every time

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an "Excel Binary Workbook" with named sheets and a MS ACCESS with queries named same as workbook sheets.

For example i have a sheet like "CustomersData" and have a query named the same.

My issue is when i run this code, it exports query data to "CustomersData1" not "CustomersData"

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 9, xQuery, strFilePath, True, xSheet
```

I was about to write function to delete firstly sheets before exporting data but i have another sheets in the same workbook have references to these sheets.

My Code:

```
Public Function Export_To_Excel()
On Error GoTo Export_To_Excel_Err

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim xQuery As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim i As Long

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Export_Specs")

strPath = "D:\Path\To\File.xlsb"

i = 0

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
            xQuery = rs("Query_Name")
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 9, xQuery, strPath, True
            i = i + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "No queries found to export.", vbCritical, "Getting Queries"
End If

MsgBox "Finished. (" & i & ") Queries were exported successfully to " & strPath, vbInformation, "Exporting Data.."


rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

Export_To_Excel_Exit:
    Exit Function

Export_To_Excel_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Export_To_Excel_Exit
End Function
```

Comment: You'll need to give us more than just a single line of code. As it stands we have no idea what `xQuery`, `strFilePath` and `xSheet` are, this information would be incredibly helpful in providing a correct answer.

Comment: @Aiken I just made an edit to my post to include my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the below replacement to your existing code should do the trick

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 9, xQuery, strPath, True, "SheetName!A1:Z200"
```

Comment: thank you. But what if i have a range wider than this preset one ?